# Проблема с поиском и корзиной open cart

Tags: opencart

У меня на сайте

> http://alexconcord.com

не работает поиск и корзина , все файлы вроде правильные , сверял с другим сайтом на opencart, пробовал перезаливать эти файлы. Но они как не были кликабельными и рабочими, так и остались.
В чем может быть причина ?
Часть кода ниже...

```
(document).ready(function() {
/* Search */
$('.button-search').bind('click', function() {
    url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

    var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

    if (search) {
        url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
    }

    location = url;
});

$('#header input[name=\'search\']').bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        url = $('base').attr('href') + 'index.php?route=product/search';

        var search = $('input[name=\'search\']').attr('value');

        if (search) {
            url += '&search=' + encodeURIComponent(search);
        }

        location = url;
    }
});
```

Файлы прикрепляю ниже

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B621Dy8PNC4dTUtoQXBkd2U1dnc/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B621Dy8PNC4dTEZfLTdHbFlrTkU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B621Dy8PNC4dMmVsZ3hackh1Y2s/view?usp=sharing
```

Comment: Почему вопрос закрыт: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код не работает из-за ошибки в в скрипте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Научитесь самостоятельно находить ошибки и устранять их с помощью:

- [Инструменты разработчика](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Tools)  в Firefox
- [Средства разработчика](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), входящие в Google Chromium

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Все легко починил.
Ниже пример уже рабочей строки

```
$('#'+'product_id').replaceWith ('<a href="index.php?route=checkout/cart/" style="color:#fff;"  title="Перейти к оформлению заказа" class="button_module_act" > Оформить </a> ');
```

А вот что было до нее

```
$(''#+'product_id').replaceWith ('<a href="index.php?route=checkout/cart/" style="color:#fff;"  title="Перейти к оформлению заказа" class="button_module_act" > Оформить </a> '();
```